# Getting -[__NSArrayI addObjectsFromArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0c5f70 error

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray

I am geting error while I am adding objects in my array
-[__NSArrayI addObjectsFromArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0c5f70

```
id max;
   NSMutableArray * MovePointsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    max=[pointsArray objectAtIndex:0];
    for(int i=0;i<[pointsArray count];i++){

        if ([pointsArray objectAtIndex:i] > max) {
            max=[pointsArray objectAtIndex:i];
            [MovePointsArray addObject:max];
        }

    }

   NSMutableArray * pointArray =[NSArray arrayWithObjects: [pointsArray objectAtIndex:0],[pointsArray lastObject], nil];
    [pointArray addObjectsFromArray:MovePointsArray];
```

Not getting wehre I am doing mistake.

Comment: What do you store in pointsArray ? how they are compared ?

Comment: I am storing CGPoint values

Comment: Allocated with NSArray!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Correct code**

```
NSMutableArray * pointArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: [pointsArray objectAtIndex:0],[pointsArray lastObject], nil];
[pointArray addObjectsFromArray:MovePointsArray];
```

You were initializing `pointArray` with `NSArray`, and `NSArray` doesn't have the method in your next line `addObjectsFromArray` which is a `NSMutableArray` method..

Comment: Also, please enable warnings and treat warnings as errors. The compiler could have told you that the method does not exist on `NSArray`.

Answer (score 5):

In last line

```
NSMutableArray * pointArray =[NSArray arrayWithObjects: [pointsArray objectAtIndex:0],[pointsArray lastObject], nil];
```

replace `NSArray` with `NSMutableArray`

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can find out your error here:

```
NSMutableArray * pointArray =[NSArray arrayWithObjects: [pointsArray objectAtIndex:0],[pointsArray lastObject], nil];
```

replace `NSArray` with `NSMutableArray`

Answer (score 1):

In the last line, pointArray, is actaully an NSArray object, not NSMutableArray.

```
NSMutableArray * pointArray =[NSArray arrayWithObjects: [pointsArray objectAtIndex:0],[pointsArray lastObject], nil];
[pointArray addObjectsFromArray:MovePointsArray];
```

Add mutableCopy in the end or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray * pointArray =[NSArray arrayWithObjects: [pointsArray objectAtIndex:0],[pointsArray lastObject], nil];
```

Change to

```
NSMutableArray * pointArray =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@[pointsArray[0],[pointsArray lastObject]];
```